# What is excel formula limit in 2010?

Tags: excel, vba, limit, formula

What is excel formula limit in 2010?

Following data doesn't display all text.

1802,2,1345,Chk Diff: -1343,Partitioned: 1345,C.D.,"=""0041,0089,008D,0091,00A1,00A9,00B1,00B9,00C1,00C9,00D1,00D9,00E1,00E5,00E9,00ED,00F1,00F5,00F9,00FD,0101,0105,0109,010D,0111,0115,0119,011D,0121,0125,0129,012D,0141,0145,0149,014D,0151,0155,0159,015D,0161,0165,0169,016D,0171,0175,0179,0189,0199,01C1,01C5,01C9,01CD,01DD,01E1,01E5,01E9,01ED,01F1,01F5,01F9,01FD,0201,0205,0209,020D,0211,0215,0219,021D,0221,0225,0229,022D,0231,0235,0239,023D,0241,0245,0249,024D,0251,0255,0259,025D,0261,0265,0269,026D,0271,0275,0279,027D,0281,0285,0289,028D,0291,0295,0299,029D,02B9,02BD,02C1,02C5,02C9,02CD,02D6,0 etc.. """

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3):

> Length of formula contents - 8,192 characters
>
> Internal length of formula - 16,384 bytes
>
> Selected ranges - 2,048
>
> Arguments in a function - 255
>
> Nested levels of function - 64
>
> Total number of characters that a cell can contain - 32,767 characters

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I had cell printed from Perl program which is mostly number and strings in csv has 6720 chars. Excel interprets as number and displays ####, So I converted it to string using formula "=""Num,String" , But excel displays only 255 chars.